# how can I disable touch scrolling on the magic mouse?

Tags: mouse, settings

I recently got a magic mouse, and have been trying to use it, but I am finding it very unfriendly to use.  Mainly I am constantly scrolling all over the place, on accident when I am moving the mouse.  Is there any way do disable touch scrolling and I will just adjust to dragging scroll bars?

Comment: no, I don't want slow the tracking speed of my mouse, that will not help me...